# how to make a self compile binaries running at other linux pc

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, centos

i was trouble in a problem, i want to compile a project, when i was finished, it's working well on the PC(centos 6.4) which i was compiled it, but when i copy the binaries file to the other pc(centos 6.4) and try to run it, there is and error about dependences:

error message:
./nano: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

and then i try to find out how many dependences was lost:

`[root@localhost ~]# ldd nano`
        `libcurl.so.4 => not found`
    `libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003959e00000)`
    `libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003959200000)`
    `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003958e00000)`
`[root@localhost ~]#`

and, i try the other pc(redhat) again:

`[root@localhost ~]# ldd nano`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /usr/lib64/libidn.so.11: no version information available (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.7 not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.11 not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /usr/lib64/libnss3.so: version NSS_3.12.5 not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.12 not found (required by /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /usr/lib64/libnss3.so: version NSS_3.12.9 not found (required by /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /usr/lib64/libnss3.so: version NSS_3.12.5 not found (required by /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2)`
`/usr/bin/checkdisk: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.7 not found (required by /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10)`
`[root@localhost ~]#`

so, anyone can help me how to make it work well on other centos/redhat？ thanks very much.

Comment: You need to install `libcurl.so.4` probably provided by some *curl* package on the remote computer. You might want to package your application (as an `.rpm` package for CentOS).

Comment: thanks very much. but i just want to build my application into one executable file, not rpm, like the difference of microsoft visual studio MD/MT compile mode, any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very hard problem.  It's just not the way things are done in most GNU/Linux distributions.  There are good reasons for both sides of this argument; Google can help you to learn about it.

It is *possible* to do what you want, which is called *static linking*.  The difficulty varies depending on the type of library you're using.  Unfortunately for you, `curl` is on the "very difficult" side, because curl itself depends on lots of other libraries; try running `ldd` on the `libcurl.so.4` on the system where it works and see how many things it requires... to fully statically link a program with curl you ALSO have to statically link all those other libraries as well... and in the right order!  That's not simple and there aren't good tools to *make* it simple, because this is not the preferred way of doing things.

So, by far the easiest solution is to use your package manager to install those libraries on the target system.  If you are building a package yourself, you can define in your package that it requires the other packages (like `curl`) then the package manager will ensure they're installed.